# linux paste and cut

Tags: linux

I have a list of phone numbers that looks like this:

LAST NAME, First name 12344
...
...

I want in a piped sequence to take only the first last names column and paste it into a new file when only the first letter is capital.
For example:

> NIXON
>
> COHEN

will be:

> Nixon
>
> Cohen

I need to do it with cut and paste commands.
I know how to cut the first latter:

```
cut -f1 -d"," phone.txt | cut -c1
```

And how to cut the rest of the letters and make them not capital:

```
cut -f1 -d"," phone.txt | cut -c2- | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

But I can't understand how to paste them together in one piped sequence.
I can use grep or sed if it helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the `phone.txt` file contains:

```
NIXON, John 123
COHEN, Tomas 345
```

---

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/^\(.\)\([^,]*\).*/\u\1\L\2/' phone.txt
```

---

***gawk*** alternative:

```
awk -F, '{print substr($1, 1, 1) tolower(substr($1, 2))}' phone.txt
```

The output(for both approaches):

```
Nixon
Cohen
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I can't use sed because I can't use \u and \L.

Comment: but you have written *I can use grep or sed*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
echo ``` cut -f1 -d"," test.txt|cut -c1``cut -f1 -d"," test.txt|cut -c2- | tr [A-Z] [a-z] ```
Output : Nixon